# Verifying Proof of decreasing functions and function composition increasing.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to prove the following:

> If $f$ and $g$ are decreasing functions on $I$ and $f \circ g$ is defined on $I$, then $f \circ g$ is increasing on $I$.

My attempt: Let $x_1,x_2$ be in $I$ such that $x_1\lt x_2$ and let $f$ and $g$ be decreasing. Then $g(x_1)\gt g(x_2)$.

Then $f \circ g (x_1)= f(g(x_1))$ and $f \circ g(x_2)=f(g(x_2))$

$f(g(x_1)) < f(g(x_2))$

So, $f \circ g$ is increasing on I.

Comment: You don't need $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_2 > x_1 \implies g(x_2) < g(x_1) \implies f(g(x_2)) > f(g(x_1)) \implies (f\circ g)(x_2) > (f\circ g)(x_1) \implies f\circ g $ is an increasing function.

Comment: Then is what I have okay even if i included the f(x_1)> f(x_2)

Comment: I edited your post and removed that part as pointed out by @Abdallah Hammam that its not necessary to have it there.

Comment: Why is f(x_1) > f(x_2) not needed?

Comment: because the proof does not use this information.